# Bubble Sort not sorting correctly

Tags: c

Hi I had written a bubble sort algorithm but it is not working as it supposed to. Below is code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(int array[], int size);
void printArray(int array[], int size);

int main(void){
    int data[] = {7, 4, 8, 1};
    int sizeOfData = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    bubbleSort(data, sizeOfData);
    printArray(data, sizeOfData);
}

void bubbleSort(int array[], int size){
    int i, j;
    int temp;
    int flag = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++){
            if(array[j] > array[j + 1]){
                array[j] = temp;
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;
            } if(flag = 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int array[], int size){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        array[i];
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Output of this program is = 1888

Please tell me what wrong I had done in my code.

Comment: Your "swap" code is wrong. Usually it's something like `temp = a; a = b; b = temp;` --- you have `a = temp; a = b; b = temp;` ... Also the use of `flag` is in the wrong spot

Comment: Activate the warning of your compilator you will get the pblm with `if (flag = 0)` , statement with no effect  `array[i];`  and ‘temp’ may be used uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

Try this, better:

```
void bubbleSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int flag;
    do {
        flag = 0;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
            int j = i + 1;
            if(array[i] > array[j]){
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (flag);
}
```

You have done several things bad in your code:

1. You assing to `array[i]` the undefined value of the uninitialized `temp` variable, you should do the assignment switching the right hand side and the left hand side.  That is the correct way of switching two array cells... and not what you have done.
2. The check for `flag` must be done outside of the inner loop, as you break from it as soon as you exchange a variable, and it is not clear if you need to continue moving the bubble up in the array.
3. The flag should control the exit of the external loop... once after you have moved the bubble through the whole array and no exchange has been done, you can exit.  I suggested in my code to use a `do {} while ()` loop, better than a `for` loop, that will confuse you, having two indexes in the inner loop, when only one (the bubble position) is needed.
4. it has been flagged in the comments, but `if (flag = 0)` assigns 0 to flag, making that always flag is `0` and the condition always false.

I use the `j` variable (derived by incrementing `i`) to avoid the writing of i+1 several times in the code.  With an optimizer compiler it is not an issue, as both codes will give the same or similar assembler code.  But with a nonoptimizing compiler, you will be calculating the value of `i+1` in several places, that can be avoided by assigning to `j` the value `i + 1`.  It could also be written as:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < size; i++, j++)
```